# Generalised Fibonacci

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

How to find the nth term of the recurrence in $\log n$ time.

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
F[n]&=&F[n-1]+F[n-3]\\
F[2]&=&1\\
F[3]&=&2\\
F[4]&=&3\\
F[5]&=&4
\end{array}
$$

I could not create the required matrix to exponentiate.

Comment: It's worth noting there is a closed form solution to this equation, it can easily be found [using this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_Recurrence_Sequence#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $F[n]=F[n-1]+F[n-3]$,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}F[n-1]\\F[n-2]\\F[n-3]\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}F[n]\\F[n-1]\\F[n-2]\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Is this the thing you want?

Comment: +1, this fits the bill. And also leads to a $\log n$ complexity calculation, as the powers of this matrix can be calculated fast using square-and-multiply.

Comment: thanks... just the thing i was looking for.

Comment: @The Great Seo can you explain the underlying logic... how did you get to dis?

Comment: @RajShah I cannot describe my 'feeling' explicitly, but here is my way: I think you already know that the form has to be ($n\times n$ matrix)($1\cdot n$ matrix)=($1\cdot n$ matrix), while ($1\cdot n$ matrix) is formed by $F[-]$s, and ($n\times n$ matrix) describes the relation between $F[-]$s. Since we have $F[n]=1\cdot F[n-1]+0\cdot F[n-2]+1\cdot F[n-3]$ as the relation, $n=3$(=# of terms in LHS).